# How to inject CSS into javascript file while compiling es2015 library

Tags: javascript, css, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm working on some React UI library and I want to use some thirdparty component like a base for my own configurable component.

This thirdparty component requires to include style files into HTML (default.css and theme.css)

I can't do it because it should be a compiled javascript library without any css etc. so users should just import a js file without any copying/including css into theirs html.

I can't use Styled Component or JSS etc. because I don't want to rewrite the whole code of the thirparty component to insert all necessary classes into tags.

So I know that webpack could extract styles from file, transform them into string and insert into the HTML document but I can't do it because webpack creates a huge big compiled file so I'm using Babel.

SO is there exist any possibility to extract css from file and transform it into script and when the user import this compiled javascript component this script should execute and insert css into HTML page?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if that can help, but with just js, injecting a stylesheet would be as follow. Note the usage of [template string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) (backtick, not mandatory but easier here), the styling will be on the bottom of the document, but this is [adjustable as need](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore).

```js
const css = `
  body {background:red}
`

let link = document.createElement("style")
link.rel = "stylesheet"
link.type = "text/css"
link.textContent = css

document.body.appendChild(link)
```

```html
<body>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi @Cryptopat. Thanks for the advice. Your tip give me an idea how to easilly solve this issue.
I placed CSS code into js files like strings and imported these strings into my Component. Then I used react-helmet to control these styles because they should be removed from head when we are moving to a next page. 

Unfortunately I didn't manage how to import CSS file like a string via babel so I just manually did it, however I don't like this way. Tried to use  *transform-css-import-to-string*  but it didn't work. Maybe because I'm running webpack while developing and compiling via babel.